# Get XML file name from loaded XML files using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

My Python code reads XML files stored at location and loads it into Python list after parsing using lxml library as shown below:

```
XMLFILEList = []
FilePath = 'C:\\plugin\\TestPlugin\\'
XMLFilePath = os.listdir(FilePath)
for XMLFILE in XMLFilePath:
    if XMLFILE.endswith('.xml'):
         XMLFILEList.append(etree.parse(XMLFILE))

print(XMLFILEList)

Output: 
[<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x000001CCEEE0C748>, <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x000001CCEEE0C7C8>]
```

Currently, I see objects of XML files.

Please can anyone help me pull original filenames of XML files. For example: if my HelloWorld.xml file is loaded into XMLFILEList. I should be able to retrieve "HelloWorld.xml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a one to one correspondence between XBRLFilePath and XMLFILEList, first one is the file you loaded, second is the file contents, just use that applying your if statement.

```
mydict = {}
for XMLFILE in XBRLFilePath:
    if XMLFILE.endswith('.xml'):
        mydict[XMLFILE] = etree.parse(XMLFILE)
```

your dict will now have as keys the files loaded, and as values the loaded files